# Finding max datetime while grouping by two other fields - SQL query

Tags: sql

first time posting here.  Apologies for poor formatting.

I have a table that contains order info.  In it there is a primary key, OrderID.  This is  generated when someone creates a cart.  The task at hand is to indicate orders purchased that have been previously purchased within the last (let's say 60 days in this case) with the same email address.  So the basic select would look like this:

```
SELECT orderid,purchasedate,emailaddress FROM basket
```

Now -- the tricky part is the MAX(OrderID) and purchasedate do not necessarily behave how you'd expect them to.  That is to say someone with the same email address could have started a cart back in January, built a new one in March, and then purchased the original one.  In this scenario, simply grabbing my max orderID will not do the trick because the biggest ID isn't necessarily the most recently purchased.  Ultimately the output I'm looking for should look something like "CurrentOrderID | EmailAddress | CurrentPurchaseDate | PreviousOrderID | PreviousPurchaseDate"

**Problem is a little difficult describe.  Basically I'm trying to select most recent purchasedate BY emailaddress but also including the corresponding orderID.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide sample data and the exact desired output based on it. [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/1920232)

Comment: Sorry, should have included that.  SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood from above description , i count suggest you below with sub-query ( format varies based on which RDBMS you use , below is for oracle )

```
select max(orderid) as orderid,purchasedate,emailaddress 
from ( select max(purchasedate) as purchasedate,orderid,emailaddress 
       from market group by orderid,emailaddress ) market_external 
group by purchasedate,emailaddress;
```

I hope this is what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In **MySQL**, the query below will join the latest purchase record with all the later purchase records.

```
SELECT 
    b1.orderId AS currentOrderId,
    b1.emailaddress,
    b1.purchasedate AS currentPurchaseDate, 
    b2.orderId AS previousOrderId,
    b2.purchasedate AS previousPurchaseDate
FROM basket AS b1 
    JOIN basket AS b2 ON(b1.emailaddress = b2.emailaddress AND b1.purchasedate > b2.purchasedate)
ORDER BY b1.emailaddress, b1.purchasedate DESC, b2.purchaseDate DESC
```

To find the record with the previous purchase date closest to the current purchase date, you can use a MySQL variable to create a counter and only select the record **having ordering = 0**. the counter depends on the order by **ORDER BY b1.emailaddress, b1.purchasedate DESC, b2.purchaseDate DESC** to work correctly. The counter is reset for each email using another variable to track when the email changes.

```
SELECT 
    b1.orderId AS currentOrderId,
    b1.purchasedate AS currentPurchaseDate, 
    b2.orderId AS previousOrderId,
    b2.purchasedate AS previousPurchaseDate, 
    IF( @previous != b1.emailaddress, @counter:=0, @counter:=@counter+1) AS ordering,
    IF( @previous != b1.emailaddress, @previous:= b1.emailaddress, @previous) AS emailaddress
FROM basket AS b1 
    JOIN basket AS b2 ON(b1.emailaddress = b2.emailaddress AND b1.purchasedate> b2.purchasedate),
    (SELECT @counter:=0, @previous:='') AS tmp
HAVING ordering = 0
ORDER BY b1.emailaddress, b1.purchasedate DESC, b2.purchaseDate DESC
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to run -- shouldn't we be using casing if you're trying to add it in SELECT?  I'm not sure IF functions properly like that.. FYI I'm running SQLServer2012

the errors I'm getting:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ':'.

Comment: this was for MySQL, i don't know the equivalent for SQLServer, sorry